# Change a string which is a number wrapped in commas, to a parsefloat (eg 3.00)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, floating-point

I am pulling in a value that is returned with commas around the number. I want to convert this to a number and then perform comparisons against another number later in my code. But I can't seem to get a reliable extraction of the number.

```
// Output from duration is ",3.000000,";
console.log('ffmpeg duration output: ', duration.toString('utf8'));
console.log('ffmpeg duration output with replace: ', duration.toString('utf8').replace(/^,/, ''));
console.log('ffmpeg duration output with parsefloat: ', duration.parseFloat);
console.log('ffmpeg duration output with parsefloat: ', parseFloat(duration.replace(',', ''));
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT: 3.00 (As a number, with two decimal places [float])**

Comment: Why would you expect 2, not 3? `duration` is a string, what are you trying to do with `duration.output` which is `undefined`? Also it is not possible to have a number with a predefined number of decimal places. That is only possible with a string.

Comment: Sorry my typo, the value of the variable duration is ```",3.000000,"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple regex should do for taking the `,` out of the string and be able to set the string for `parseFloat`.

```
duration = duration.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Assumption here: `duration` is where the string `",3.000,"` is. Otherwise, replace `duration` with wherever that string is.

Comment: Could this be wrapped in a single line with parsefloat?

Comment: `parseFloat(duration.replace(/,/g, ''));`

Comment: If a string is actually a number "3" will JS see it as a number when used in comparisons? ie ```5 > duration is true?

Comment: Yes, JS  will see it as a number if it is 3.